# C# Как написать событие когда 1 label касается другого

Tags: c#, label

Подскажите пожалуйста, как написать событие когда один label касается другого?

Comment: такого события у тип Label нет, при каких условиях должно происходить наложение позиций объектов? Изменение размеров формы или что-то еще? Не хватает подробностей

Comment: О каком label идет речь? Это webforms, winforms, WPF, Silverlight?

Answer (score 6):

В общем случае будет достаточно такого метода:

```
    public bool CollisionDetection()
    {
        var rectangle1 = label1.Bounds;
        var rectangle2 = label2.Bounds;

       return rectangle1.IntersectsWith(rectangle2);
    }
```

Метод необходимо вызывать в функции, отвечающей за передвижение label'ов.

Comment: `if () return true; else return false;` выглядит не круто. Почему не написать просто `return ...;`

Comment: @Aндрей для наглядности. Что бы человек точно понимал, что происходит в коде. Плюс, возможно, человек захочет еще как-то обработать событие.

Comment: Но при желании можно и так: `return label1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(label2.Bounds);`